# Wordpress : display all articles of a month on one page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to change the default behavior of Wordpress regarding the number of articles displayed on a same page to be the following :

- when displaying the home page, the 10 most recent articles should be displayed, 10 being the setting which can be changed through the admin panel (posts_per_page)
- when displaying the articles of a specific month (given through the URL like this : `?m=200906&order=ASC`, I'd like to display on the same page all articles of this month (in other words, I don't want to have to browse through articles using *previous entries* or *next entries*.

EDIT : I forgot something else I'd like to change :

On the page where all articles of the specified month are displayed, I would like to display the comments for each article.

Is this possible to do ? How ?

Answer (score 4):

in your archive.php, add this on top of your template:

```
$allowedOrder = array('ASC', 'DESC');
if(isset($_GET['m'])){
   $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? (in_array($_GET['order'], $allowedOrder) ? $_GET['order'] : $allowedOrder[0]) : $allowedOrder[0];
   $m = $_GET['m'];
   $y = substr($m, 0, 4);
   $m = substr($m, -2);
   $query = "posts_per_page=-1&year=$y&monthnum=$m&order=$order";
   query_posts($query);
 }
```

Or, if you just have one big index.php template file, do this:

```
$allowedOrder = array('ASC', 'DESC');
if(is_month()){
   $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? (in_array($_GET['order'], $allowedOrder) ? $_GET['order'] : $allowedOrder[0]) : $allowedOrder[0];
   $m = $_GET['m'];
   $y = substr($m, 0, 4);
   $m = substr($m, -2);
   $query = "posts_per_page=-1&year=$y&monthnum=$m&order=$order";
   query_posts($query);
}
```

For more detail, look at codex page:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: thanks for the tip. I added the code to my archive.php and it working fine, except that now, I cannot use anymore the order=ASC (see updated question). Am I doing something wrong ?
Also, do you have an idea how to display all comments after each displayed article ?

Comment: you know, query_posts can fix that for you. Just add 'order=ASC' to $query. As for second question (comments on each article) you can open up another SO question with detailed problem. post it here so that I can see the URL.

Comment: If I understand well, adding the sorting in $query will force this sorting, where I would prefer to get the sorting given through the URL. Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: see my new SO question regarding comments : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409988/wordpress-always-display-comments-with-articles

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using query_post if you look at the codex page it gives you details of how to do this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

Answer (score 0):

Check out `WP_query` also there are some differences between `query_posts` and `WP_query`.
Both are used to create queries for custom loop. If you want better control over query use  `WP_query`.

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query
3. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts