# Wordpress : always display comments with articles

Tags: wordpress

When displaying all articles of a specific month (given through the urls like this : `?m=200906&order=ASC`, I would like to display, following each article, all comments regarding this article.

In the `article.php` of the default theme (the one I'm using), I tried to add the following line :

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

before the line

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

(as I've seen it in `single.php`) but it doesn't work and I don't really now what I could try next.

Comment: What loop are you using? Or are you using a new query to get your posts?

Comment: Comments_template includes the form for adding comments

Comment: @songdogtech : I'm using the standard loop in the archive.php file. I didn't change anything other than what I said in my question, as I've got no idea how all that stuff is working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php $withcomments = "1"; comments_template(); ?>
```

From [Include Tags « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Include_Tags#The_Comments_Template)

Comment: Works great !
Do you know if there is any way to display the comments, but not the input box to add a new comment ?

Comment: Depends on the comments_template code in your theme (probably in comments.php), but you can edit that, such as removing `<?php comment_form_title(); ?>` or similar. Make a copy of your comments_template first.